# Batch file variable manipulation

Tags: batch-file

Does anyone know why this is not working? I want it to ask for a string, such as 1, 2 or exampletext. Then it checks if the input value is 1, then it changes the variable to ABC, if it's 2, then it changes to DEF, otherwise leave it the same.

```
@echo off
set /p id="Enter ID: " %=%
IF "%id%" == "1"(
   set id="ABC"
)
ELSE (
   IF "%id%" == "2"(
      set id="DEF"
   )
   ELSE (
      PING 127.0.0.1 -n 0.1 >nul  
   )
)
Start "" "C:\Users\Comp\Desktop\livestreamer-1.5.2-win32\livestreamer.exe" twitch.tv/%id% mobile_High
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although Joey already indicated the cause of the error, I can't resist the temptation to show you a different method to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the table of equivalences:
set equiv[1]=ABC
set equiv[2]=DEF

set /p "id=Enter ID: " %=%
if defined equiv[%id%] (
   set id=!equiv[%id%]!
) ELSE (
   PING 127.0.0.1 -n 0.1 >nul  
)
Start "" "C:\Users\Comp\Desktop\livestreamer-1.5.2-win32\livestreamer.exe" twitch.tv/%id% mobile_High
```

This method use an *array*. If you are interested in this method, search for "Delayed Expansion" and "Arrays in Batch".

Comment: It uses several environment variables that look like an array ;) – but indeed, that's a nice option if the list of possible values gets longer.

Comment: Array? There is no single array in batch. `:-) `

Comment: @Endoro: Excuse me "Ansgar", I forgot that! `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

You're just missing a few spaces (before the opening parenthesis in the `if`). And `else` needs to go on the same line as the closing parenthesis¹:

```
IF "%id%" == "1" (
   set id=ABC
) ELSE (
   IF "%id%" == "2" (
      set id=DEF
   ) ELSE (
      PING 127.0.0.1 -n 0.1 >nul  
   )
)
```

Note also that quotes after the `=` in `set` are included verbatim in the variable, which isn't what you want here.

You can also simplify a bit:

```
if "%id%=="1" (
  set id=ABC
) else if "%id%=="2" (
  set id=DEF
) else (
  ping localhost -n 1 >nul
)
```

---

¹ Which is even spelled out in `help if` on the very first page: “The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.”

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that 1-2 spaces can cause the errors. I'm still new to batch coding.